# Why doesn't em font-size resize on responsive grid?

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I've created a responsive grid and used em as the font-size to make the text resize, but I must not be fully understanding how em's work as there is no resizing of text.

Live site:
http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/shop.html

Following Ethan Marcottes book I've set the body font to `font-size:100%` and then made by text within the cpation on the page linked above as 2ems - so double the base size... Am I doing it wrong? It doesn't seem to change at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/jm3sK/

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code in a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/)? It's hard to know what "the caption" is.

Comment: I've added a JS Fiddle but I'm trying to get it work responsively, it's hard to get it working on a small case because of the nature of the size reducing based on browser width. I'm giving it a go. The captions, however are the white thick writing with the prices on on each image. They are 2em's in size but they don't change when the browser window width is adjusted.

Comment: How were you intending that they'd resize? A responsive layout has to with the width of the viewport--not the size of the fonts.

Comment: Your jsfiddle's `.caption` `em` does change the size of the font. I changed it to `1em` and `4em` both works in chrome browser. Which browser is giving you problems?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, I don't see it resizing at all

Comment: Ok, I think I read your situation wrongly the first time. Responsive layout-wise, you need @media queries to change font size, according to screen width or screen height changes. Just setting an `em` fixes the font-size relative to the base font-size, that doesn't make your font resize when your screen's dimensions changes. Responsive grid only adjust widths of content containers and the flow of elements, additional styling has to be declared in CSS manually.

Comment: The website given does not work... change or question makes less sense.

Answer (score 11):

I think what you are looking for is `@media`queries. `Em` is not a magic-bullet unit that will resize based on the browser width. It is a relative unit.

If you want any CSS to change based on the browser width, use [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

`em`s are useful in this case because you only have to change one value (`body{font-size}`) to scale all the rest of the page. Because they are relative, not because the the browser changed. You can use these techniques together.

Here is a quick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b4FKY/). Resize the window.

```
body{font-size:100%;}
i{font-size: 2em;}


@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    body{font-size: 150%;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    body{font-size: 200%;}
}
```

​

Answer (score 5):

The `em` unit means the size of the font. It does not depend on browser window width at all.

The [`vw` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length) relates to the window width: it means 1/100 of the viewport width. But it has limited and buggy support in browsers.

Comment: I'm reading Ethan Marcottes book on RWD and it suggests using EM's due to their flexibility and that they can be used where a set pixel size shouldn't be used. Is this not correct?

Comment: The `em` unit is flexible indeed, but when used for `font-size`, it makes the size vary by the parent element’s font size. To vary font size or other presentational issues by window width, you can use `@media` queries.

Comment: How can I make it vary by the parent elements font size? Is it possible to make it vary as the caption div it is in changes size?

Comment: By definition, setting `font-size: 2em` sets the font size to 2 times the parent element’s font size. But this does not depend on the size of the parent element at all; it depends on what has been set to its font size.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, I've recently come up with a solution.

If you define all text within the body as a percentage and then resize the text within the body on document.ready and on window.resize, the text remains 100% responsive.

e.g.

```
CSS
font-size: 100%;

JavaScript
function fontResize(){
    var perc = parseInt($(window).width())/125;
    $('body').css('font-size',perc);
}

JQuery
$(document).ready(function (){
    fontResize();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    fontResize();
});
```

Comment: What an answer. I wasted two days with CSS for Iphone screen issue. Thank you for your best solution with JS.

Answer (score 0):

In recently researching this issue myself for responsive design... I came across this wonderful table: http://www.hubbers.com/index.php/converting-px-into-percentage-and-em-for-relative-css-font-sizes/

It breaks down the conversions between: pixels, em's and percentages within the table but even better, it provides the simple formulas to convert these from one to another which was very helpful in my case as I was determining font-size dynamically

I was similarly thinking that making font sizes percentages would force them to re-size like other elements when the window resizes... but that does not work (although it should in my opinion). In the end I ended up using media queries as stated by Bookcasey along with the formula mentioned above to convert the percentages back to em's.

Answer (score 0):

I think that table is quite clear and shows well the reason why fonts can't scale with window resizing.
The reason is that ems, percentage and even rems are relative to the browser default font (that is usually 16px) not to the measurement of the browser window.
So if you write "font-size: 100%;" is like writing "font-size: 16px;" and not "font-size: 100% of the window ize".
If you write "font-size: 200%;" is like "font-size: 32px;" etc...

To create a layout with fonts that continuously scale with window resizing I think you could use jquery. 
Maybe a mix of "$( window ).resize" and ".css('font-size','value')" could work...